# Como usar una trasaccion para englobar multiples insert en diferentes funciones

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hola amigos alguno de ustedes sabe como puedo utilizar una transacción en c# pero abarcar múltiples funciones, ya que debo insertar a mas de una tabla y la información de todas ellas para armar un documento de compra. pero para esto si alguna de la información no fue insertada o genera algún error debo de hacer un rollback para que no se guarde el resto de la información, pero tengo los insert de cada tabla en diferentes funciones por cuestiones de validaciones. todos mis insert esta dentro de la misma clase.

Comment: Bienvenido @Erick te invitamos a visitar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para una mejorar las preguntas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es crear una instancia al objeto `TransationScope`, en seguida tus operaciones en la base en este caso las funciones y para que aplique las operaciones solo invocar al método `complete`

Ejemplo:

```
try
{
    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
    {
       //Tus operaciones en base datos Update,insert delete o tus funciones
       transaction.Complete();//para aplicar los cambios
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{

}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu repuesta. Me fue de gran ayuda